# Excel VBA fill row after row according to the value of another column

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I want to make a macro that modifies the table in the following way: each time column A is filled manually with the value "1", I would like all the rows in column A to take the value of "1" as soon as column B contains the same value as the first filled cell. If I put 1 in cell A4, I would like that everywhere where B contains "Ananas" put a 1, so in A2, A3, A10, A11... Then if 1 is entered manually in A7 (b7 = "Kiwi"), I would like 1 to be put in A15, A16, etc... I have 5000 lines with also empty values in B.

Here image of Excel sheet

[image: 1]

Comment: Please provide the code you've tried thusfar.  If you're looking for a tip/hint, look into change events.

Comment: sorry I did some tests but they didn't work at all...

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you want. This is a worksheet event so it must be placed in the worksheet coding module.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim c As Range
    
    For Each c In Target.Cells
        If c.Column = 1 Then
            
            Dim newVal As Variant: newVal = c.Value
            Dim match As String: match = c.Offset(0, 1).Value
            
            Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
            Dim lastRow As Long: lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
            Dim r As Long
            For r = 2 To lastRow
                If ws.Cells(r, 2).Value = match Then
                    ws.Cells(r, 1).Value = newVal
                End If
            Next r
            
        End If
    Next c

    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: it works!! Thank you very much :)
However, when I want to delete the values in column A, it gives me an error. I would like the values to be deleted if necessary...

Comment: what did you try

Comment: I tried to delete the values "1" of the column A in case of changes.

Comment: It works just fine for me. That being said, you did not even attempt to resolve the issue on your own. Mark my solution as correct if you view it as such. Good luck!

Comment: i'm just learning and my code wasn't good enough to be published... i tried though. i also validated your answer. despite the low tolerance with beginners,, thanks anyway

Comment: My intention is not to be short with you. What is the error you are recieving?

Comment: Ok thank you, it's written : 'Execution error 13 : incompatibility of type'

Comment: I fixed the problem with the command "on error go to..."
Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Good stuff! If you don't mind me asking, what line was the error occurring on?

Comment: the error appeared if I deleted the values of several lines at once, from A2 to A15 for example.

Comment: I've updated the code to respond correctly to your test case. While GoTo Tags and error handling are perfectly fine, it is better, in general, to try to solve the actual error if possible.